# iOS client using AFNetworking is sending JSON params with "%" characters to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, urlencode, afnetworking, parameters

My iOS device is sending JSON params to my Rails server and when I output the contents to console. I see that weird characters are in the params hash. The server method then cannot create an object with these params. And nothing is saved in the database.
How do I fix this?
Thanks

Code that sends the JSON from iOS device:

```
    //Create a Dictionary of Parameters which will be convertedto JSON object
     NSMutableDictionary *mutableParameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    [mutableParameters setObject:_entryID forKey:@"id"];
    [mutableParameters setObject:fnameExt forKey:@"image_file_name"];
    [mutableParameters setObject:_lat forKey:@"lat"];
    [mutableParameters setObject:_longitude forKey:@"lng"];
    [mutableParameters setObject:_description forKey:@"description"];

     NSMutableDictionary *photoDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObject:mutableParameters]
      forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"photo"]];

     //Create a Request Object
      NSMutableURLRequest *mutableURLRequest = [[appAPIClient sharedClient]
                                          multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                          path:@"/photos"
                                          parameters:photoDict

      constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
                                          { .....}
```

My rails server

```
 # POST /photos
 # POST /photos.json
 def create
    @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
    puts "Photo ="
    puts "Server received Photo with attributes= #{@photo.inspect}"
    @photo.save
 end
```

Console output on Server

```
 15:11:19 web.1  | Photo =
 15:11:20 web.1  | Server received Photo with attributes= #<Photo id: nil, lat: nil, 
  lng: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, image_file_name: "someFile.jpg", 
  image_content_type: "image/jpeg", image_file_size: 0, image_updated_at: "2013-02-
 18 23:11:17">

  15:11:20 web.1  | Started POST "/photos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-18 15:11:17 -0800
  15:11:20 web.1  | Processing by PhotosController#create as JSON
  15:11:20 web.1  |   Parameters: {"photo%5BentryID%5D"=>"1", 
  "photo%5Blng%5D"=>"-122.406417", "photo%5Blat%5D"=>"37.785834", 
  "photo%5Bimage_file_name%5D"=>"someFile.jpg", 
  "photo%5Bdescription%5D"=>"Description", "photo"=>{"image"=>#
  <ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fa314c07768 
  @original_filename="someFile.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-
  Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo[image]\"; 
 filename=\"someFile.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#
  <File:/var/folders/dh/1k2rdp_51yd2k43xzkc2pmdh0000gn/T/RackMultipart20130218-2872-
  13gqqo5>>}}
```

Comment: So I am not following what the weird characters part is.

Comment: note the % characters inserted in the params?

Answer (score 1):

The iOS client is encoding the parameter names as URLs.  For example "photo%5BentryID%5D"  is "photo[entryID]"  you need to unencode them, though that process should have been done automatically on the server side, you should check that your iOS client isn't double encoding them.

Comment: Hi @Mike Walston thanks for the response. Im new to this, could provide some ide as to how to unencode these or even what unencode means. Any sample code, websites would be great.
Thanks